# Why I cannot connect to GCP Redis Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, nestjs, connection, bull

I'm trying to connect to a Redis Instance of Google Cloud Platform but it hasn´t succeed.
I am working with Bull and NestJS.

This is how I have  setup the conection to Redis Instance in the app.module file:

```
 BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: '172.20.11.8',
        port: 6378,
        password: '1bwb48bd-46d4-432r-bd5d-pd18b91ff438',
      },
    }))
}
```

When the app starts, it does't show any error of connection or something like that but when I add a task in a queue, I check the status connection and it says "connecting" and doesn't work.
I don't know if I am sending something wrong in the data of the connection.

When I work with a local redis instance, I have no problema working with redis. The problem is when a try to connect to the remote Redis Instance.

The password in the connection is the AUTH string that GCP gives when yo create the Redis Instance.

Comment: Did you check firewall rule?